# How to set a 200x200 background of an image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, background, resize

I am currently creating an app which will let you upload some images and then resize them (100x180) and put a 200x200 white background on them.

I've figured on how to resize the images + create the white background but I cannot figure out how to put them together.

Here is the code for resizing and the white background:

```
 public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
    {
        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

        destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
            }
        }

        return destImage;
    }

private Bitmap DrawFilledRectangle(int x, int y)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(x, y);
        using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            Rectangle ImageSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, x, y);
            graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ImageSize);
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Expected result:

[image: a busy cat]

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Instead of the destination image in the first method being a new `Graphics` object, use the white rectangle created in the second method. Or before you draw the image to the new graphics object, call `graphics.Clear(Colors.White);`

Comment: @RonBeyer Could you please show it in code because I am not sure if I understand (I am pretty bad with graphics)?

Comment: Just call `graphics.Clear(Color.White);` after the `graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;` call in the first method. You'll also have to offset the image (instead of drawing it at 0,0) if you want it centered/at the bottom like the picture you posted.

Comment: Adding this line didn't change anything, sadly.

Comment: Ron's advice will help. No need for the DrawFilledRectangle if you clear(white) the whole area before drawimaging the image into the center.. - How is it not working?

Comment: Thank you. I had to make the destImage variable 200x200 in order to see the background. Now I have to figure out how to center the image :)